# Wrap `HttpListener`'s `GetContextAsync()`

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to wrap the `HttpListener` class and added more logic which deals with Web Sockets.

Finally, I'm trying to wrap the `GetContextAsync()` method to only return `HttpListenerContext` objects which are web sockets.

So far I have:

```
public Task<HttpListenerContext> GetContextAsync()
{
    Task<HttpListenerContext> contextTask = listener.GetContextAsync();
    if (contextTask.Result.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        return contextTask;
    }
    else
    {
        contextTask.Result.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        contextTask.Result.Response.Close();
        return GetContextAsync();
    }
}
```

But When I call the outer function (of the wrapper class), using:

```
HttpListenerContext listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
```

The `await` won't return to the main thread until a first connection is achieved.

---

#### EDIT

If it helps someone, I ended up going with the following:

```
public async Task<HttpListenerContext> GetContextAsync()
{
    HttpListenerContext listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
    while (!listenerContext.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        listenerContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        listenerContext.Response.Close();
        listenerContext = await listener.GetContextAsync();
    }
    return listenerContext;
}
```

Comment: Well, what did you expected to happen? When you await a task the execution will not return to the await point until the task has been completed...

Comment: I expected that while the `await` waits for the task to finish, the main thread will continue. Isn't it what `await` does?

Comment: No, it does not, `await` freeds the thread to be used by the `TaskScheduler`, that doesn't means the execution will continue. If you don't want to wait to the end of the task execution then don't `await` the call. Also, as you are using the `Result` property of the task it will block the thread. So you must NOT await the call and NOT use the `Result` property, convert the function to `async`, inside the function `await` the `listener.GetContextAsync()` and use the result, in this way it will not block.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect what @gusman says

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look closely at your method:

```
public Task<HttpListenerContext> GetContextAsync()
{
    Task<HttpListenerContext> contextTask = listener.GetContextAsync();
    if (contextTask.Result.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
```

You are making the contextTask block the thread until it gets some response by using Result:

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

Basically, you need something like this:

```
public async Task<HttpListenerContext> GetContextAsync()
{
    HttpListenerContext context = await listener.GetContextAsync();
    if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        return context;
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        context.Response.Close();
        return await GetContextAsync(); //not sure here
    }
}
```